# Find and create empty files with the same name in another location

Tags: bash, find, touch

I want create empty files with the same name, but in another location.

Is it possible?

1. find some files
2. use only filenames
3. touch an empty file in another place

Something like this:

```
find . -type f -name '*.jpg' -exec basename {}.tmp | touch ../emptys/{} \;
```

Comment: Do you want the subdirs recreated below `emptys/` or just files?

Comment: Stick an `xargs` before the `touch` and you're close. Though I don't understand what the `.tmp` is supposed to be. Is it an extension for removal, or are you appending to the filename?

Comment: I want recreate all jpgs inside emptys/ folder with the extension .tmp. Like photo01.jpg.tmp

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you can use the `--attributes-only` switch of `cp` for this purpose, eg.

```
find . -iname "*.txt" -exec cp --attributes-only -t dummy/ {} +
```

From the `man` page of `cp`:

```
--attributes-only

don't copy the file data, just the attributes
```

This will create empty files with all attributes of the original file preserved but no contents.

Comment: Note that's GNU only. It doesn't preserve attributes unless you tell it which ones to preserve with `-p` or `-a`. You might as well use `-exec cp --attributes-only -t dummy/ {} +` here to avoid running one cp per file.

Comment: Thanks Ketan. I improve your suggestion with -exec cp -u --attr...

Answer (score 2):

Without recreating the subdirectories:

```
find . -type f -name '*.jpg' -printf /path/to/emptys/%f\\0 | xargs -0 touch
```